# Soap call times out from some of my servers

Tags: php, soap, timeout

In my code I am creating a SOAP Client and then calling a web method to get the response.
Creating the SOAP client works fine but when I call the method it times out at 60 seconds. Have set the connection timeout at 60 secs. The thing is, it fails from certain servers only and works fine on others(we have a cluster of servers and should have the same configuration ). When it is successful, it gives response in less than a second.
What could be the issue ?
These cluster of servers are behind a public IP so shouldn't be an IP filtering issue.

Comment: Well what did you do to debug this? By checking access.log and error.log you can verify it's actually hitting the servers.

Comment: Kindly share error logs, and some code snippet of the web method